# Send Javascript Push Notification - AFTER Form POST and URL redirection

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect, push-notification

Use case (Django Project):

I want to log in on my login page -> Therefore I use this form in html (login.html):

```
<form class="loginform" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="loginform">
        {{form.as_p}}
    </div>
    <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success loginbtn" value="Login">
</form>
```

In case of successful log in I will redirect with DJANGO to this URL (localhost/welcome/)-> welcome.html:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "welcome"
```

I am able to send javascript notifications with alertify, but only when using simple things such as
click on it or mouseover:

```
function notification(text) {
console.log(text)
alertify.success(text);
}
```

I tried it with onsubmit="javascript:notification("")" in the html form tag, however this will
be displayed only BEFORE the URL redirection.

So my question is:

- How is it possible to activate /send the push notification AFTER the URL redirection and in
  case of successfull POST/ Log in?

I really appreciate your help! Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is client-side. That means your `alertify.success(text);` will be executed client-side, once server already did his render process.

The authentication process is server-side. So you have to make your server make your alertify a part of the rendered content.

Knowing that, you just have to change your `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` content page to include in it a call to notification:

```
<!-- your html template comes here -->
<script type="text/javascript">
notification('You are now logged in');
</script>
```

Be remembered that the notification will then display each time the person visits this page. You may want either to redirect him again, or to introduce a variable in Django to avoid displaying it again.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I think I try to implement it in this way with a separated html file or similar